How to format a given string of numbers to the Russian currency format?
I have the following input JSON
{
    "listPrice": "1245678.98"
}

I need to format this to the following format
{
"listPrice": "1 245 678,99"
}

Currently i'm being able to do this via the below script
payload.listPrice as Number as String {format: "#,###.##"} replace "," with " " replace "." with ","

Is there a better way to do this, maybe using locales? I tried the Russian and Polish locales, but they didn't work.
EDIT: I also tried this script
payload.listPrice as Number as String {format: "#####,##", locale: "ru-RU"}


Add to the question what you tried.

I think i found the issue with what I did

payload.listPrice as Number as String {format: "#,###.##", locale: "ru-RU"}

This should be the correct way to do it. I was using the wrong format while trying to convert it to the Russian currency format.
I was using "####,##" instead of "#,###.##"

You are almost there. Try this:
payload.listPrice as Number as String {format: "# ### ###,##"}

instead or replacing your way to the target format.

Thanks, I tried this, but now I'm getting spaces at the end :/
"listPrice": "1,24,56,79  "  << something like this   and it also looks like it's rounding off the decimal values as well.
